# How to restrict access to applications in Big Sur?

Tags: big-sur

How do I put FaceTime in a folder and assign a password to the folder? The aim is not to have access to the apps without password.
I actually want to restrict access to minimize distraction ( tv app, FaceTime, App Store) and I was able to do that without any problem in Catalina, but with Big Sur it's another story.

I have already tried using screen time but I don't think parental control is the solution to my problem as I want to use the Mac for academic use.  I wanted to prevent myself from being distract by them, but still use safari without any problem. I actually did try activating screen time, but it's not effective (as I explained in screen time, we aren't able to to activate "Downtime limitations" and "limits apps" but still use Safari) so I'm looking for solutions.

Comment: Can you share some information about your usage scenario here? Do you want to prevent getting called, do you want to prevent calling out, do you want to keep a minor away from Facetime, etc? Depending on this there might be better solutions to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes,this Mac is used by a lot of persons and  it's in order to prevent people from being distracted. I already try screen time but it's wasn't good for that. In fact, Safari missing from the list of apps '"always allowed apps " so I can't select Safari as an Always Allowed app in order to exclude it from Downtime.

Comment: There are also Parental Controls in combination with having one user account per actual user. But please edit more details into the question to explain the use cases here.

Comment: Basically, I don't think parental control is the solution to my problem as I actually want to restrict access to distraction ( tv app, FaceTime, App Store) and I was able to do that without any problem. As I want to use the Mac for accademic use, I wanted to prevent myself to be distract by them but still use safari without any problem. I actually activate screen time, but it 's not effective ( as I explained  in screen time, we aren't able to  to activate "Downtime limitations" and "limits apps"but still use Safari) So I'm looking for solutions

Answer (score 1):

I personally don’t recommend blocking things that you as the administrator can unblock, but I understand friction can be good for many people so I would encourage use of screen time - if only to show you the amount of time you spend so you ca track that and build healthy habits over time. Also, it’s quick and easy so start with it while you wait for other answers to arrive.

1. You can not delete apps in a meaningful way to accomplish your goal in Big Sur. It’s not easy and you have to circumvent the sealed system / patch and update process. Plus you may waste more time than you save in a week, but have at it if someone documents a solution there.
2. Use Screen Time to block whole apps.
3. Use the SelfControl app to block sites in Safari (and other browsers) https://github.com/SelfControlApp/selfcontrol/wiki/FAQ

Be sure you read the self control FAQ. It has some amazing gems of wisdom in it. Good luck tailoring your experience - don’t be out off by parental controls or screen time instructions - that’s the best way to block things without breaking the OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have access to FaceTime, simply *Sign Out* from FaceTime.

1. Open the FaceTime app
2. Select Preferences
3. Click Sign Out

Then nobody can FaceTime you, nor you can FaceTime to anyone without logging in to the app again.

If you just want to disable some apps, create another user account *without* administrative privileges and then apply Screen Time restrictions to that account.

Likewise if there are multiple users sharing the Mac, create at least one user account per person and then you can apply unique restriction profiles for the respective user accounts.